# SPWorkflow.Tasks is empty when not in debug

Tags: workflow, tasks, properties, evaluation

I'm facing strange problem. I have following code to get last item workflow and its task item.

```
var wfCol = item.Workflows;
if ((wfCol == null) || (wfCol.Count == 0))
    return null;
var wfItem = wfCol[0];

// this condition is never true when not in debug
if ((wfItem.TaskList != null) && (wfItem.Tasks.Count > 0)) {
....
}
```

I can never go inside the condition, because **wfItem.TaskList** is null and **wfItem.Tasks** throws Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

However, when I use debug and add breakpoint before **wfItem.TaskList** is called, it will go inside the condition. I have found out that when in VS I disable **Property evalution**(Tools -> Options -> Debugger -> Enable property evalution) it behaves just like without breakpoint.

Is there any option to force Sharepoint to do the same like Debugger does property evalution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is a nasty hack :-/ I am not proud of it, but it is working.
I just called

```
var tmp1 = wfItem.TaskList;
```

and

```
var tmp2 = wfItem.Tasks.Count;
```

before I really need those properties. So they get loaded and condition is finally correctly evaluated